# CPU usage discrepancy

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I have a program for which I need to track how much CPU it is using. Inside the program, I do that by calling `clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,...)` once every second and reporting the result.

I also monitor that thread using the `top` command.

While top claims that specific thread is taking 70%-90% of the CPU, `clock_gettime` only advances about 250ms each second (i.e. ~ 25% CPU usage).

I am running on Ubuntu Linux 18.04, kernel 5.4.0-72-generic, on Intel X86_64.

I'll add that I'm also measuring the wall clock time spent outside of my main `epoll`, i.e. - the wall clock time I'm idle. That shows that I spend ~80% of the time idling on the epoll (i.e. - more or less agrees with my in-thread measurement). On the other hand, I'm having some problems that seem to indicate too high CPU usage by the thread.

What might be the cause of such a reporting discrepancy? Which one of the two shows the actual usage?

**Clarification**
I'm using `htop`, and asking it to separately report different threads. The CPU usage is for the *thread* in question.

Comment: `top` by default reports CPU usage for the entire process - are you using `-H`?

Comment: Of course. Otherwise everything makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

After further digging into the issue, it turns out that `top` actually agrees with the CPU utilization measured by the program itself (around 25%). It seems that `htop` has a bug on that front, likely counting sub-threads' CPU usage under the main thread's title, even when displaying said subthreads explicitly.

I have verified this by changing the main thread's code to just open a thread and `join` it, thus ensuring its actual CPU usage is 0%. `htop` still reports it as highly active.

It is a pity, as `htop` is a more convenient program to work on in almost any other way.